# How to set default action handler permanently?

Tags: default-applications

I've set defaults apps for many actions like sending email, opening PDFs, opening webpages etc. But, when I install or update an app which could handle that action, this default is cleared (even if default app is updated).

Nobody has problem with this because they can tick default checkbox on next action. My problem: I use Tasker to automate high amount of actions. And, due to this default removals (after automatic update), my tasks are stuck at `Choose App` pop-up. Tasks need to be completed in time. So, I face many real-world problems due to this.

What should I do to preserve defaults after automatic app update. Please, don't answer `You can't` or `Turn off Automatic Update`.

Comment: This is a comment so I can say it: You can't, turn off automatic update. If you're a developer than hypothetically speaking you could write an app that would be notified when an app is updated and could set the default handler (I think you might need root for the last part.) Maybe the developer of Tasker has some insight to this?

Comment: I'm afraid Richard is right here. I just checked with the Tasker API in the hope it would provide its own solution (as I'm affected by the same issue, just not that hard). Though Tasker can react on "Package Updated" (and even gets to know which package), there's no action to handle "default apps". And I'm not aware of any system setting like "do not reset default app on update". Maybe some programmer develops a little tool to care for "forced app defaults", listening to the package_updated intent, and simply sets all defined defaults again...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, defaults on Android is not preserved if apps that use the intent are changed.

## Workaround:

Use **intent** to launch the application or its activity screen.

**intent** is comparatively reliable though it may be changed when app is updated.

Take sending email as an example

1. Install [Intent Intercept (Google Play)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept)
2. Clear the defaults of email client
3. Choose "Intent Intercept" in Share menu when sending email
4. Copy intent details of your desired application activity
5. Open Tasker to "Create Task": Misc > **Send Intent**
6. Edit the parameters (Usually fill in the Action and Extra is enough)

Ref: http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/intents.html

P.S. Some famous companies even provide you the intent details on their developer website, such as Evernote.

Comment: That app is open source, also available here: http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=intent%20intercept&fdid=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept